# React Native Android emulator Setup on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: react-native, ubuntu, android-emulator

I installed Ubuntu 19.10 recently, 
react-native , node everything installs fine, but when I try to run the react-native android-run , Emulator NOT found error is keep on coming up.

I am not yet familiar with all the ubuntu commands

Android Studio version 3.6.1

Answer (score 0):

I need a little more information. Can you edit your question and show

1. the EXACT command that you use, and
2. the EXACT error that you see?

That will help us see what needs to be done. Thanks.